# Unable to add to array from function using arguments

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function `getPrice($_SESSION['external']);`

```
function getPrice($position)
    {
        //Here I perform SQL functions using $position['arraykey']
        //This works

        //Here I want to add to the array
        //This doesn't work
        $position[0]['pricing'] = $sql_result;
    }
```

When I use `$position` it doesn't add to the array, but when I use `$_SESSION['external']` it works fine.

I'm not sure why `$position` works in the SQL query part of my function but one line bellow when I try to add the result to the array, it doesn't.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by *it doesn't* ? Have you done any debugging ?

Comment: @Rikesh Using $position[0]['pricing'] to add to my array doesn't work. Using $_SESSION['external']['pricing'] does.

Comment: Can you create a `pastebin` of your code snippet ?

Comment: try with $position['pricing'], else please be more specific about your array thing..

Comment: @Rikesh Sure http://pastebin.com/WbvCFXj3

Comment: You need to return your resultant array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the $position variable by reference
Like below:

```
function getPrice(&$position)
    {
        //Here I perform SQL functions using $position['arraykey']
        //This works

        //Here I want to add to the array
        //This doesn't work
        $position[0]['pricing'] = $sql_result;
    }
```

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you very much, wasn't aware of passing by reference. Works perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelN Btw, it's not recommended to modify your function parameters; consider returning the modified variable instead.

Comment: @Jack Why isn't it recommended? I'll look into returning as well. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelN 1. because of the function name and 2. because immutable design is generally better for stability.

Comment: @Jack & @ Michael N: yes,  it is better way to return from function instead of modifying function parameter.